# System.NullReferenceException in a class library

Tags: c#, excel, excel-dna

I'm trying to configure some connection strings in app.config, but keep getting this error message,

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

I've looked at numerous solutions on the web, but nothing directly applies,

- I'm copying the app.config file to the target directory
- I've referenced `System.Configuration` and am using `ConfigurationManager`
- The XML / source is almost a verbatim copy of the Microsoft [guidelines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254494(v=vs.80).aspx)

The only difference is that the project is a class library, which I'm exposing to Excel via ExcelDNA.

Is there something special I need to do to get this to work with Excel?

Here's a snippet of the XML,

```
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="ConnectionCSV" providerName="System.Data.OleDb" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" />
    </connectionStrings>  
</configuration>
```

This is the source code (have got a `using System.Configuration` along with necessary reference),

```
string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionCSV"].ConnectionString;
```

The above line throws the `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of the configuration file needs to match the name of the .XLL file that is created by ExcelDNA.

e.g.

`MyApp-AddIn.xll` -> `MyApp-AddIn.xll.config`

`MyApp-AddIn64.xll` -> `MyApp-AddIn64.xll.config`

Comment: Thanks a lot, Caio. You hit the nail on the head!

Answer (score 1):

- Libraries don't have their own `app.config` files, they belong to the parent executable.
- Excel.exe does not have its own `app.config` file.
- The connection string `ConnectionCSV` does not exist in whatever configuration file, if any, is being used at runtime. You can verify this by checking if `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionCSV"] != null` first and warning the user if the key doesn't exist.

In your case it might be better to store the connection string in the user's registry instead. To whit:

**Update**:

I just found this page on MSDN which describes your exact problem and explains how you *can* use `app.config` files with Office add-ins: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/16e74h9c.aspx

Specifically:

> In the [app.config filename] box, type the same name as the assembly plus the extension .config. For example, a configuration file for an Excel project assembly called `ExcelWorkbook1.dll` would be named `ExcelWorkbook1.dll.config`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Dai. That further clarification helped. File this question under '_bleeding obvious_'. ;-)